# Can't get POST parameters in controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I'm experimenting with Symfony and I am trying to make a POST request. But I can't seem to get the request's POST parameters inside my controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/messages/comment/post/", methods={"POST"}, name="postComment")
 */
public function postComment($messageId, $comment)
{
    $statuscode = 200;
    $response = null;
    try {
        $response = $this->messageModel->postComment($messageId, $comment);
    } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
        var_dump($exception);
        $statuscode = 500;
    }
    return new JsonResponse($response, $statuscode);
}
```

How do I define parameters for this?

Comment: What you are trying to do exactly? what is this variable messageModel? where is it defined? please be more clear

Comment: messageModel inserts the posted parameters into the database. What I'm trying to do is catch $messageId and $comment as post. But how do I define those parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get POST parameters inside a controller you should use:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
....
/**
 * @Route("/messages/comment/post/", methods={"POST"}, name="postComment")
 */
public function postComment(Request $request){

    $messageId = $request->request->get('messageId');
    $comment = $request->request->get('comment');
    ...
}
```

Documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for indeed.